# Method for randomly loading paired images

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a webpage with many (over 100) paired flash cards with Question (image) flipping to Answer (image) when clicked. If possible I would like to be able to randomise the order in which the question/answer pairs load with each page load/refresh.

```
    <div class="content4Column gap">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card click" data-direction="left">
      <div class="front">
            <img src="Intermolecular/Q1.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
            <img src="Intermolecular/A1.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you want to use only Javascript? For example, with PHP you could have all your question/answer pairs in an array and each time the page loads you can shuffle the array and output the data in a new sequence. Let us see what you've done so far

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm an amateur and have only used Javascript and PHP that I've found online and tweaked to fit my needs. Open to any and every suggestion. I have researched and looked at a lot of scripts but can't see how to change them to do what I want.

Comment: I assume your question cards are always call Q[X].png with X a number from 1 to X and your answser card are always call A[X].png with X a number from 1 to X.

I think a solution could be to create an array A. Stock in A, 1 to X numbers. Pick a randomized number B between 1 to A.length, display and remove A[B].

Do the procedure while A.length != 0.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

Comment: Thanks for replying. You are correct about the numbering of my Qustion and Answer images. I can understand the logic behind picking the randomised number B from original array and have seen some examples of how to do this. How do I then allocate the numbers to make the images load randomly?

Comment: If it make it easier to visualise what I'm doing, here is link to web page [link](http://new.chemistry-teaching-resources.com/FlashCardIntermolecular.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var QAPairs = [];
var QATotal = 200;  // total numbers of QA pairs
var QA = 20;  //number of QA pairs you want. Set to QATotal to include all QA pairs
while(QAPairs.length != QA){
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*QATotal);
  if(QAPairs.indexOf(rand) == -1){
    QAPairs.push(rand);
    //  If you want to show them all at a time
    document.getElementsByClassName("card click")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("card click")[0].innerHTML + '<div class="front">\
            <img src="Intermolecular/Q' + QAPairs[i] + '.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />\
        </div>\
        <div class="back">\
            <img src="Intermolecular/A' + QAPairs[i] + '.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />\
        </div>';
  }
}

// if you want to show them one at a time
var i = 0;
function updateCard(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("card click")[0].innerHTML = '<div class="front">\
            <img src="Intermolecular/Q' + QAPairs[i] + '.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />\
      </div>\
      <div class="back">\
            <img src="Intermolecular/A' + QAPairs[i] + '.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />\
      </div>';
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I don't know how to transfer the new number (QAPairs) into my code above. I presume it will need to replace the "1" in Q1 and A1 with a new random number (QAPairs). And so on for Q2,A2 etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You've bee very kind to give me so much help. I will try it and report back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @adminXVII but so far I cannot get this to work but I will keep trying.

Comment: @GordonWatson If you want, you could put your code in a JSFiddle and send me the link so I could help you

Comment: Think I've managed that @adminXVII. Here is link https://jsfiddle.net/ginneswatsonkelso/ucLqw23g/

Comment: @GordonWatson just remove the window.onLoad part and **closing img tag** and it works! JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucLqw23g/1/

Comment: Congratulations @adminXVII and many many thanks. I see that is working in jsfiddle but (at the moment) I still can't get it to work in my full web page. There may be issues with other scripts running (?) or other javascript libraries (?). Unfortunately, I'm on holiday and stuck behind a hotel firewall that prevents me uploading the webpage or I'd ask you to see if you can see anything obvious. I return home next Sunday so may ask another favour, but you have helped me enormously already and I'm very grateful. Meantime I'll try removing things to see what might be interfering.

Comment: Making some progress. It works once I shift the script into <body> as long as it comes after first appearance of "card click". However, instead of loading an image into each instance of "card click" it seems to be loading all the images into the first "card click". Refreshing the browser does change the order of the cards loading and question/answer pairs are intact which was crucial.